# Kotlin generics to java without wildcards

Tags: java, kotlin, code-generation

Example Kotlin class:

```
class Example {
    private lateinit var creator: (Unit) -> String
}
```

Equivalent in java will be

```
class Example {
    Function1<? super Unit, ? super String> creator
}
```

How can I annotate field creator to avoid using of wildcards?

Comment: Why exactly do you need those wildcards? Just remove them? I don't see any problem here. Otherwise specify your question further.

Comment: Yeah, not sure what you're asking either. When interfacing with java, the generated getter function for `creator` doesn't have wildcards. Also I suspect this is due to this being an example, but a function taking a `Unit` as a paramter doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Your wildcards are wrong, it should be `? extends String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove wildcards by using `@JvmSuppressWildcards`:

```
lateinit var creator: (@JvmSuppressWildcards Unit) -> @JvmSuppressWildcards String
```

By the way your code won't generete wildcards, so following code is perfectly valid without any annotations:

```
new Example().setCreator(new Function1<Unit, String>() {
     @Override
     public String invoke(Unit unit) {
         return "Test";
     }
});
```